# Getting the value of a control in a class C#

Tags: c#, class

I'm working on setting up a login form for an existing application. I'm currently having issues with getting the value of one of the text boxes in a class.

For example Form9 has a textbox called txtchannel. I'm wanting to get the value of what's in txtchannel in the class.

// Revision

I was finally able to get it to take the command using the following

// Class

```
    private void DoConnect()
    {
        try
        {
            jtvClient.Connect();
            jtvClient.JoinChannel("#" + this.mainForm.txtChan.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            op.Post(x => OnExceptionThrown((Exception)x), ex);  // TODO: double check that exceptions
        }                                                       //       actually show up at this level
    }

    private Login mainForm = null;
    public JtvClient(Login derp)
    {
        mainForm = derp as Login;
    }
```

////

This is allowing me to at the very least call the what is in Login(Now Formally Form9). However it gives an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". I'm at a complete loss.

Comment: You mean the text value? `txtchannel.Text`

Comment: On the same form or you wanna use it in another form?

Comment: did you tried to make the access modifier for this control to public ?

Comment: I have made this public @ Eslam.

Comment: I am indeed referring to txtchannel.text @ Meda.

Answer (score 2):

I think the **Text** property of the **TextBox** class is what you are looking for.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the full documentation on `TextBox.Text`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get the value in another class (if you mean another class), is to expose a property called `Channel` in `Form9`. The would look like this:

```
public string Channel
{
  get
  {
    return txtChannel.Text;
  }
}
```

Comment: After trying this it appears that the control is still not being defined within the class. The only that that comes forth is ChannelMessage

Comment: I don't know what you want to do exactly? I assumed that you want to expose the value of channel text box on *Form9* for using in other forms.

Comment: Sorry if it was worded poorly. I'm trying to get what is in txtChannels.text to be read in a class

Comment: Ok, but in the same class (Form9) where the txtChannels defined or **another** class?

Comment: From Form9 where the txtChannels is defined to a class file added as Shift + Alt + C (Empty Class Definition.) Sorry I've migrated from vb6 to C# and haven't gotten all of the lango down just yet. >_<

Comment: So you wanna use it in another class, then just define the property on *Form9* then use it in your *NewClass*. The *Form9* must be instantiated before and the text box must be filled before use. Usage would be st. like *form9.Channel*. I still don't know your scenario though.

Comment: I've tried multiple methods T_T I am certainly not getting the hang of this C# the way I thought I was.... If it makes it any easier I can always livestream it and show you. I have tried using all sorts of methods to define the property.. I'm not really getting anywhere -_-